# share folder windows storage 2008 R2

Tags: network-programming, share

I was wondering if it is possible to `Disable auto login` to access shared folders on network.

Every time I access the share folder using IP address `(ex: \192.168.1.4)`
it opens easily. 
But I want client to always input user name and password every time they want to access network shared folders.

I want to do some thing like

1. check connection

   ```
   if on connection then(do nothing)
   else(force login screen the next time client want to access share folder)
   end
   ```

I would be grateful if anyone can help me with this problem.

Comment: First of all; there is some kind of webserver serving up files on your remote machine. You will need to figure out what it is. If you still can't figure it out I suggest you come back to SO and tell us what you tried

Comment: In remote machine I just share some folder to specific user as full control.   I did nothing other than that.   The user will need to input id and password to login for the first time only.

Comment: Is there anyway to monitor the access idle time, and after reach limit time I want to disconnect it.